# error generator in Julia JuMP optimization error

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I am converting a code in julia 0.6  to 1.2. 
Here is the old version:

```
@variable(model, use[i=eachindex(n), j=1:m], Bin)

Used  = [indmax(getvalue(use[i,j])
                           for j=1:m) for i=eachindex(n)]
```

I converted to the following,

```
@variable(model, use[i=eachindex(n), j=1:m], Bin)

JuMP.optimize!(model)
Used = [argmax(JuMP.value(use[i,j])
                    for j=1:m) for i=eachindex(n)]
```

but with error:

```
MethodError: no method matching keys(::Base.Generator{UnitRange{Int64},getfield(Main, Symbol("##261#266")){Int64,JuMP.Containers.SparseAxisArray{VariableRef,2,Tuple{Any,Any}}}})
Closest candidates are:
  keys(!Matched::Core.SimpleVector) at essentials.jl:606
  keys(!Matched::Cmd) at process.jl:963
  keys(!Matched::BenchmarkTools.BenchmarkGroup) at /Users/shuaiwang/.julia/packages/BenchmarkTools/7aqwe/src/groups.jl:31
  ...
pairs(::Base.Generator{UnitRange{Int64},getfield(Main, Symbol("##261#266")){Int64,JuMP.Containers.SparseAxisArray{VariableRef,2,Tuple{Any,Any}}}}) at abstractdict.jl:132
_findmax(::Base.Generator{UnitRange{Int64},getfield(Main, Symbol("##261#266")){Int64,JuMP.Containers.SparseAxisArray{VariableRef,2,Tuple{Any,Any}}}}, ::Colon) at array.jl:2068
findmax(::Base.Generator{UnitRange{Int64},getfield(Main, Symbol("##261#266")){Int64,JuMP.Containers.SparseAxisArray{VariableRef,2,Tuple{Any,Any}}}}) at array.jl:2065
argmax(::Base.Generator{UnitRange{Int64},getfield(Main, Symbol("##261#266")){Int64,JuMP.Containers.SparseAxisArray{VariableRef,2,Tuple{Any,Any}}}}) at array.jl:2153
(::getfield(Main, Symbol("##260#265")){ScenarioGraph,JuMP.Containers.SparseAxisArray{VariableRef,2,Tuple{Any,Any}}})(::Int64) at none:0
iterate at generator.jl:47 [inlined]
collect at array.jl:606 [inlined]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be unrelated to JuMP. The fix to your code is:

```
Used = [argmax([JuMP.value(use[i,j]) for j=1:m]) for i=eachindex(n)]
```

(I have not tested the whole code as it was not complete)

And the core of the issue is that you are not allowed to use `argmax` on generators, you have to pass a collection that supports `pairs` to it, e.g.:

```
julia> argmax(i for i in 1:3)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching keys(::Base.Generator{UnitRange{Int64},getfield(Main, Symbol("##15#16"))})
```

fails, but

```
julia> argmax([i for i in 1:3])
3

julia> argmax((1,2,3))
3

julia> argmax((a=1,b=2,c=3))
:c

julia> argmax(Dict(:a=>1,:b=>2,:c=>3))
:c
```

work